# Two Bootstrap tabs appear active at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have five tabs that are using Bootstrap for animation. They were working fine until I added the final tab: Management. When I click the Management tab the SuperAdmin tab displays as still active in the nav. But when I click the SuperAdmin tab I do not have the same issue. The management tab is then inactive. So the issue is only happening one way. I did some copy and paste from that tab when I created the Management tab because the design was similar. I assume that's what is causing the issue, but I can't find the exact problem.

I did try to remove the active class from the SuperAdmin tab when the Management tab was clicked, but that did not seem to work:

```
<script>
$("#management").click(function () {
    $("#super-admin").removeClass("active");
});
```

[image: When Super Admin tab is selected]

[image: When Management tab is selected]

Here is the nav:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="navTabs">

<li @(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Create") ? Html.Raw("class=\"active\"") : Html.Raw("")) > @Html.ActionLink("Add Record", "Create", "Home")</li>

<li @(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Search") ? Html.Raw("class=\"active\"") : Html.Raw("")) >@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "Home")</li>

@if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin") || User.IsInRole("Manager"))
        {
            <li @(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Category") ? Html.Raw("class=\"active\"") : Html.Raw("")) >@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Category")</li>
        }

@if (User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin") || User.IsInRole("Manager"))
        {
            <li @(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("SuperAdmin") ? Html.Raw("class=\"active\"") : Html.Raw("")) >@Html.ActionLink("SuperAdmin", "Index", "SuperAdmin")</li>
        }
@if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
        {
            <li @(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Management") ? Html.Raw("class=\"active\"") : Html.Raw(""))>@Html.ActionLink("Management", "Index", "Management")</li>
        }
        <li >@Html.ActionLink("Logoff", "Logoff", "Home")</li>

    </ul>
```

The best I could do to show this in jsFiddle:

Super Admin selected:

https://jsfiddle.net/s3f3cjon/

Management selected:

https://jsfiddle.net/9sd1faub/3/

You can see that the Super Admin tab still has the class active.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you replicate the issue on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sure, I'll post it in a few minutes

Comment: Because of the .net elements I am using I'm not able to replicate in jsFiddle. I could add any other code as necessary here if you think the error is not in the code block shown above. I did add some pictures for clarity

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML. The .net is irrelevant here. You should create a code snippet in your question, or link to an example at a site like bootply.

Comment: Okay, let me try that out

Comment: Could you also post the whole uri of when you are on the management tab?

Comment: When i'm on the management page the uri is /Management

Comment: `Uri.AsbsoluteUri` returns the whole uri (e.g. `http://www.contoso.com/catalog/shownew.htm?date=today`). In your JSFiddle, I see that your Super Admin's link href is `/Manage` and not `/SuperAdmin` whereas your Management's link href is `/Management`. I'm thus guessing that the absolute URI would be, for the management tab, something in the likes of `http://www.blablabla.com/SuperAdmin/Management`. Is it possible?

Comment: The url is just `http://www.blablabla.com/Management`

Comment: Do you think this is happening because the word manage is in management and I am just asking if the the uri contains that word. Which would be true for both I suppose

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. I think `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` gives you the mapped URL (which can be changed depending on the framework you use). If, instead you check for the `Request.RawUrl`, it will check in the unmapped url. I don't guarantee it'll solve your problem, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: That didn't fix the issue, but another solution just fixed it. I'll post my solution in one minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seemed to be happening because I was checking to see if the Absolute Uri contained the word 'Manage', which was true for both tabs. Instead of going through and changing my controller name I just changed the routing to a new name, 'SuperAdmin'.

So in my RouteConfig I mapped the controller route to SuperAdmin:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "ManageRoute",
            "SuperAdmin/{id}",
            new { controller = "Manage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then checked to see if the Uri contained that instead:

```
<li @(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("SuperAdmin")
```

This fixed the issue for now.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for the `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("Management")` when you click the Management Tab.

Could it be that the url contains the word SuperAdmin or Admin in the path when you navigate to Management Tab?

Try debugging the application and check for the `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.